# NetBeans 10 with GlassFish 5 is terribly slow - EAR Application

Tags: ear, glassfish-5, netbeans-10

I aim to build an EAR Application on Netbeans 10. Even though the EAR is just a empty application at moment with just a default page of "index.html". But running the application is terribly painful and slow. It took over 45mins for the html contents to appear on Browser.

Does any one know this issue?? Would greatly appreciate any input.

My Mac (High Sierra 10.13.6) has 4GB RAM and I never had this kind of issue.